# Laravel 5.1 - View variables(specifically current controller name) for a controller

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

What I wanna do is to know, inside a view, if I'm in a specific controller or not. From what I know, I've got two choices and I don't have the answer to either of them :-D

- inject a view variable using the `share` method in my `AppServiceProvider`, which involves getting the current controller name(or at least the action name so that I can switch it) inside the service provider.
- inject a variable to all the views returned in the controller. For example does controllers have a boot method? Or can I override the `view()` method in the following code snippet?

  `public function someAction(Request $request) 
  {
      return view('someview', ['myvar' => $myvalue]); 
  }`
- well of course there's the easy (yet not easy :|) solution: add the variable in all methods of the controller. I don't like this one.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the controller's construct function.

Add this to the top of your controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    view()->share('key', 'value');
}
```